# SQL Server database synchronization issues

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two SQL Server 2008 Enterprise databases (on two machines), and one of the databases is master database and another database is slave database (master database is read/write, slave database is readonly). I want to have daily update from master database to slave database (i.e. new data inserted/updated/deleted in master database could be synchronized to slave database daily or manually controlled). I only need to sync several tables of the databases, not all of the database.

Any solutions or documents?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: search for 'snapshot replication'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option in is [SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).
[Here's a tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm) giving you an overview of what it can do.
The tutorial is for SQL Server 2005 but the concepts remain the same.

You can run the packages manually or they can be scheduled.

HTH

Comment: I only find import, export and copy functions in SSIS, any update function in SSIS?